# Regex Pattern for filename like XX_XXXX_XXXX_DDMMYYYY

Tags: c#

I am retrieving a set of files from a Directory. The file names are in the pattern XX_XXXX_XXXX_DDMMYYYY. Where XX stands for the country prefix. The valid prefixes are IN,ID,SG,MY. The next set of XXXX is CCMS which is fixed. The next set of XXXX vary. 
I have the below code which I would like to optimise.

```
    string[] filePath = Directory.GetFiles(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InputFiles"]);
            foreach (string inputfilepath in filePath)
            {
                try
                {
                    if ((inputfilepath.ToUpper().Contains("HK_CCMS_CARDO_") || (inputfilepath.ToUpper().Contains("ID_CCMS_CARDO_")) || (inputfilepath.ToUpper().Contains("IN_CCMS_CARDO_")) || 
                        (inputfilepath.ToUpper().Contains("MY_CCMS_CARDO_")) || (inputfilepath.ToUpper().Contains("PH_CCMS_CARDO_")) || (inputfilepath.ToUpper().Contains("SG_CCMS_CARDO_")) || 
                        (inputfilepath.ToUpper().Contains("TH_CCMS_CARDO_")) || (inputfilepath.ToUpper().Contains("TW_CCMS_CARDO_"))))
                    {
    // Do Something
    }
    }
```

I want to replace the each inputfilepath.ToUpper().Contains("HK_CCMS_CARDO_") with a pattern search which will fit the pattern I have given earlier.
Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not using regular expression, but something like this could remove some redundancy:

```
var prefixes = new string[]{
  "HK_CCMS_CARDO_", "ID_CCMS_CARDO_", "IN_CCMS_CARDO_",
  "MY_CCMS_CARDO_", "PH_CCMS_CARDO_", "SG_CCMS_CARDO_"
};
foreach(string inputfilepath in filePath)
{
  try
  {
    if(prefixes.Any((string prefix) => inputfilepath.ToUpper().StartsWith(prefix)))
    {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

If I were to use a regex, I would probably just generate the regex string using `String.Join('|')` to concatenate the pieces and add the date part on the end, but since you're not really trying to match a format so much as a number of known prefixes I kind of think the above is clearer.

Comment: You really should not do `.ToUpper().StartsWith(prefix)` but instead do `.StartsWith(prefix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`, it performs a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

`(IN|ID|SG|MY)_CCMS_(\d|\w){5}_\d{8}`

Take note that you will need to validate the date at the end of the string.